# Spark Decision tree with categorical variables

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata

My data has categorical variables (response and some of features variables).

How can I convert it to `libsvm` format after converting the categorical variables to binary features?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is an RDD you may call the method: `saveAsLibSVMFile(rdd, path)` It's part of `apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils` package.

For official documentation see: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils$

Here's a scala example assuming you have converted your categorical data to binary features: (you can do the same in python or java too)

```
val responseData=sc.textFile("response.txt")
val responseValue = responseData.map(line => line.trim().split(" ").map(_.toDouble))

val featuresData=sc.textFile("features.txt")
val featuresValue = featuresData.map(line => {
  val featureInt = line.trim().toInt
})

val data = featuresValue.zip(featuresData).map(
  line => LabeledPoint(line._1, Vectors.dense(line._2))
)

saveAsLibSVMFile(data, "data.libsvm")
```

If you want the PySpark Version, haven't tested this but something like:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import SparseVector
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint

responseData=sc.textFile("response.txt")
responseValue = responseData.map(lambda line: map(lambda x: Decimal(x), line.strip().split(" ")))
# for clarity you can also extract the lambda into a function

featuresData=sc.textFile("features.txt")
featuresValue = featuresData.map(lambda line: Int(line.strip()))

mtx = zip(featuresValue.collect(),featuresData.collect())
data = map(lambda line: LabeledPoint(line[0], Vectors.sparse(line[1]), mtx))

saveAsLibSVMFile(data, "data.libsvm")
```

Comment: what is features.txt only categorical data or all features? and will the code work with removing all "val" in python.

Comment: All Features. I am assuming you have already changed categorical to binary features. The code will need a minor of modification to work with PySpark

Comment: Thanks. I made some changes but i am getting some error with zip which says "zip argument must support iteration. Also i tried by removing zip word but then error is map() must have atleast 2 arguments.Please help.

Comment: I updated the zip `mtx = zip(featuresValue.collect(),featuresData.collect())` you probably need to make the RDD fetch all the records before zipping

Comment: Is this working for you. I am getting error with (line._1) thing in scala which says found unit required double.What to do?

Comment: and will the output have 3 columns of response data?